# How to pass user profile name to chrome by window.open

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working for a task in which I need to pass the login user profile name of chrome by window.open() when a new tab will be opened. My project will use chrome to open and it will open as a desktop application. I have several links which are opening in new tabs. These tabs should be open in the login user profile of chrome.

Answer (score 1):

In short: you can't.

`window.open` will create a new tab in the same instance that is currently running. If they're already in a logged in instance of Chrome, it'll stay that way. If they aren't, it'll also stay that way. You'll just have to make sure your user is using a logged in instance.